# calling function declared with and without default parameter leads to different results?

Tags: swift

I wrote this code for testing (learning) purposes in a playground:

```
import Cocoa
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, c :Int = 0) -> Int {
    return a + b + c;
}
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, c :NSObject) -> Int {
    return a * b * c.description.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
}
```

And when I used it I got this:

```
DoIt(4, 5, 6);            // result: 20
var obj = NSObject();     // result: NSObject
DoIt(4, 5, obj);          // result: 520
```

I expected the first function `DoIt(Int, Int, Int)` called when doing `DoIt(4, 5, 6);` but apparently the other is being called. Where did the`6` go? It looks like the `6` was implicitly converted into an `NSObject`, In objective-c that would rise a warning at least.
Why is this?

Curiously if I make the last `c: Int` required (by removing the `= 0`) then it works as expected.

```
DoIt(4, 5, 6);            // result: 15
var obj = NSObject();     // result: NSObject
DoIt(4, 5, obj);          // result: 520
```

---

**Edit1**: Added IR
In case this helps to understand what is going on I issued the following command and the result is in the gist link: https://gist.github.com/nacho4d/94fdb72d8a3fee0c09e5

```
$ swiftc \
   -emit-ir /Users/nacho4d/Desktop/function2/function2/main.swift \
   -sdk Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
```

Comment: There is a thread on reddit, maybe it helps: [Why Swift compiler convert implicitly Integers and other primitives to NSNumber](http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2em7ic/why_swift_compiler_convert_implicitly_integers/)

Comment: I don't know why it works this way, but I don't believe this is intended behavior. It would seem very strange to me if it is.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianDressler I just read that thread. I understand implicit boxing (primitive to NSNumber) and its opposite unboxing. But I am not sure this is the case here. This is still unclear to me

Comment: @nacho4d is there actually a possibility to view generated IR code of swift? If that is the case, one could see what happens here.

Comment: Added the generated IR output here: https://gist.github.com/nacho4d/94fdb72d8a3fee0c09e5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ["Functions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) in the Swift documentation (emphasis added):

> External Names for Parameters with Default Values
>
> In most cases, it is useful to provide (and therefore require) an
>   external name for any parameter with a default value. This ensures
>   that the argument for that parameter is clear in purpose if a value is
>   provided when the function is called.
>
> To make this process easier, Swift provides an **automatic external name**
>   **for any parameter that has a default value**. The automatic external
>   name is the same as the local name, as if you had written a hash
>   symbol before the local name in your code.

So your first function declaration

```
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, c : Int = 0) -> Int
```

is treated by the compiler as

```
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, c c : Int = 0) -> Int
```

with an external parameter name "c" for the third parameter. This function
would have to be called as

```
DoIt(4, 5, c: 6)   // result: 15
```

But the call

```
DoIt(4, 5, 6)
```

*does not match* the declaration of your first function, only that of the other function

```
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, c :NSObject) -> Int
```

(and the third argument is automatically bridged to `NSNumber`, which is a subclass
of `NSObject`). That's why you get the "unexpected" output.

If you change the declaration of the first function to

```
func DoIt(a: Int, b: Int, _ c : Int = 0) -> Int
```

(where `_` stands for "no external parameter name")
then you will get the expected output:

```
DoIt(4, 5, 6)   // result: 15
```

Comment: This explains a lot of things!. Now I clearly see that for functions with optionals parameters I need to use the external parameter name or use the `_` in the declaration :). However I still don't understand how an `Int` is converted to an `NSObject` implicitly?

Comment: @nacho4d: Swift automatically bridges certain native types (Int, Float, Bool, ...) to NSNumber, which is a subclass of NSObject. You can read more about it in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/), section "Working with Cocoa Data Types". – I have updated the answer to make that more clear.